# how to get the text background only filled (creating flag)

Tags: css

I am trying to create a flag using css
Issue is that my text is in between and the area where there is text, there is no back ground color so it looks awkward. Please see the image attached
[image: Current Image]

CODE:

```
.Caption {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.Caption span {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: '.';
    position: relative; left: -25px;
    border-top: 25px solid navy;
    border-left: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid navy;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -40%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

**TIRED**
I tried to use the background property but then it not only does the background red, but also the front part too. I want the front part to be transparent and fill the text part with color. Look in the image below to see how it went far out of the text area
here is the code for that

```
.Caption span {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: '.';
    background-color:red;
    position: relative; left: -25px;
    border-top: 25px solid navy;
    border-left: 26px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid navy;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -40%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

[image: Red Color is extended besides the text]

**HTML**

```
<span class="Caption">up to 50% off</span>
```

**DESIRED RESULT**
I am trying to get rid of the red triangle (funnel etc) on left side of last image. so that only the text has the background

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with CSS? (Thinking of cross browser compability)

Comment: html is simple just call the <span class="Caption">up to 50% off</span>

Comment: I don't understand what you're desired result is.

Comment: I tried to explain that above. I am trying to get rid of the red triangle on left side. so that only the text has the background

Comment: @Autolycus can you create jsfiddle with your issue? I tried(http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/kNRbT/) and of course there is no such result as on your picture.

Comment: it needs some internal css...its a general question and I think an expert would know what I mean. I dont think we need to reporoduce that on jsfiddle